# In a matched case-control study, what do I use for hypothesis testing in the descriptive statistics or the "univariate" associations?

Tags: case-control-study, univariate

I am doing a case-control study with 80 disease cases matched 1:3 to non-diseased controls and examining whether they had a binary exposure prior to developing the disease. I am using multivariable conditional logistic regression for the main analysis. My question is, for the "descriptive" or "univariate" table where we try to investigate simple associations of each (non-matched) variable with the outcome, do I just use something like a chi-square test and ignore the matching, or do I use main effects conditional logistic regression (or something else)? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the word "descriptive" statistics here (I would limit "descriptive" and "univariate" to summary or detailed descriptions of single-variables—e.g. histograms, mean and standard deviation, median and IQR, etc.). I would instead use language like "bivariate tests for association."

To test whether prevalence of exposure in cases differed from prevalence of exposure in (3x) controls, I might recommend reading Miettinen's generalization of McNemar's test (McNemar's test is a $\chi^{2}$ test that accounts for the individual *matching* of the case data with the control data):

Miettinen, O. S. (1969). Individual matching with multiple controls in the case of all-or-nothing responses. *Biometrics*, 25(2):339–355.

You might also consider Cochran's *Q* test (which is a nonparametric analog of repeated measures/blocked design ANOVA for nominal data).

Cochran, W. G. (1950). The comparison of percentages. *Biometrika*, 37(3/4):256–266.

Comment: Thanks, both of those a good suggestions (and you are right of course about the bivariate/univariate thing).

Comment: Feel free to click the check mark if you feel this is an acceptable answer.